# Touchpad not working in Windows 10, but does in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, touchpad

System info:

- ASUS X551C Notebook PC
- 64-bit OS
- x64 based-processor

Problem:

I have recently upgraded OS to Windows 10. My laptop has two operating systems: Ubuntu and Windows 10. Whenever I switch on to Windows 10, for the first few minutes the touch pad works, but after that it doesn't work at all. I face this problem only in Windows 10, as there is no such problem in Ubuntu.

Presently I'm using a USB mouse, without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and installing the Windows 10 touchpad drivers from [ASUS' site](http://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/557/0/1/NjTBDAvwQa2EHvsG/45/) and see if that solves your problem.

It's unlikely but the problem could be something to do with the touchpad delay in Window's settings. Go to *Settings > Devices > Mouse and Touchpad* and disable touchpad delay.